# Setting breakpoints mid jQuery `animate()`

Tags: javascript, jquery

#### [jsFiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/pjNZa/)

I want to be able to set up breakpoints mid-animation. Is there any way to do this?

Comment: @SLaks: sorry, edited question to make sense

Comment: I'm still not sure what you mean.

Comment: I don't think the question makes any more sense now than before. Do you want to break during the animation? If so I think you'd have to insert a conditional breakpoint into the animation algorithms, though perhaps there's a way to do it at a hight level. I'm pretty sure you'd have to edit the jQuery code though

Comment: @Codemonkey: so basically not possible unless I want to get my hands dirty?

Comment: Not to my knowledge. If you told us why you need to break during an animation, perhaps we could point out what you're doing wrong?

Comment: that function is a callback, it's being fired **after** the animation is done. **You can't break it in no way**

Comment: How can the function that provides the data for the animation be called after the animation is done?

Comment: I have five things being animated at once and am also doing some calculations based on their height, it pretty involved so I can't fiddle up a demo

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's a step event in the animation events. You can use that.

Here's an example :

```
$("myelement").animate({
    "height":"+=500px"
},{
    duration:500,
    step:function(currentHeight){
       //do what ever you want here.
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Why would you want to do this? But if you insist, how about placing a breakpoint at this line:

```
$('div').slideUp('slow', function() {
```

and then stepping (into) through the code one statement at a time. This will take you into the jQuery code where the animation is performed. If you use an unminified version of jQuery, you'll be able to see the code which performs the actual animation.